# Positioning a "list" of images

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm making an sponsors activity containing 3-6 ImageView's which are suppose to listed vertically on top of each other. And of course be scrollable if they don't fit the screen.

Below I try to illustrate how it should look like.

image1

image2

...

imageX

As of now I'm simply positioning the images with absolutly positioning. What would be a more dynamic way taking different screen sizes into account?

Comment: How about using a ListView? You can create a view for the entries with only a single ImageView.

Comment: use jQuery mobile? it can resize the image to the screen size...

Comment: You should use a custom Listview for that. Check this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: @David I can't mark your comment as accepted answer... so if you want the credits please "upgrade".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments:

A simple [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) with a custom layout for the entries should do the trick.

For everyone who doesn't know how this would works: [Here](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-listview-with-iconsimages-and-sharks-with-lasers/) is a post about an app with a listview which contains country names and there flags as pictures.

The important part is the listitem.xml file which later gets inflated in the getView(...) method of the custom ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

Use a scrollview with a relative layout inside of it and then inflate a custom layout which basically has your images and add them to your relativelayout during runtime using the layout inflator and also setting a top margin on each of the custom layouts

Comment: I appreciate your comment but I went with a listview.

Comment: Well the reason why I suggested using a relativelayout was because it sound like you wanted to stack images on top of each other

Answer (score 0):

Use a scrollview add linear layout inside it and then inflate a linear layout and add images one by one in linearlayout which has been inflated. be sure the orientation of linearlayout should be vertical.